# Sort Multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, dimension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort a multi-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648405/sort-a-multi-dimensional-array)

How to sort the following array?
array_multisort doesn't seem to do the job.

```
Array
(
    [2009] => Array
        (
            [name] => 2009
            [20100923WO2010107543A2] => 20100923WO2010107543A2
        )

    [2006] => Array
        (
            [name] => 2006
            [20080403US20080078500A1] => 20080403US20080078500A1
        )

    [1984] => Array
        (
            [name] => 1984
        )

)
```

Sorted Form

```
Array
(
    [1984] => Array
        (
            [name] => 1984
        )

    [2006] => Array
        (
            [name] => 2006
            [20080403US20080078500A1] => 20080403US20080078500A1
        )

    [2009] => Array
        (
            [name] => 2009
            [20100923WO2010107543A2] => 20100923WO2010107543A2
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're trying to sort the array based on the keys. Use `ksort()`.

Comment: Thank you very much.
You are a life Saviour...